# center div in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css

i have the "main" div here : 
http://tallevi.net/daniel/?page_id=5
if i change the screen resolution the div is not in the middle, currently the css of the "main" div is :

```
.#main {
width: 680px;
position: absolute;
right: 35%;
padding: 0 40px 5px 40px;
font: normal 14px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
line-height: 20px;
display: inline-block;
z-index: 2;
background: url(images/content_back.png) repeat-y;
}
```

wha'ts wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to centre an element is using `margin: 0 auto;`, try changing your code to:

```
#main {
  width: 680px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 40px 5px 40px;
  font: normal 14px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: url(images/content_back.png) repeat-y;
}
```

Margin: 0 auto sets an "automatic" margin for the right and left, essentially centering it. (This only works if you specify a set width, which you have)

Comment: if you want to add IE6 compatibility, you'll have to use `text-align: center` too (on the parent element) and `text-align: left` on #main. Afaik, IE6 completly ignores `margin: 0px auto`

Answer (score 0):

set the margin of Div `margin:0 auto;` and apply other required property as you needed.

Answer (score -1):

Remove all the style from the div and apply the following css:

```
.centerdiv
{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0 40px 5px 40px;
  font: normal 14px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: url(images/content_back.png) repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: You have used the class `.centerdiv`, which the OP doesn't have. You also removed a lot of the styling he wanted, though you seem to have edited that in.

Comment: He can add the class centerdiv in his stylesheet and then use it whenever he wants, that's better than applying a style to a certain element.

Comment: well search around http://tallevi.net/daniel/wp-content/themes/kingsize/style.css and remove all the style that has to do with body, wrapper, main-wrap and leave only the above.

Comment: thanks for the try i realy appriciate that , i thing i will try solution width table , you have any idea?

Comment: i dont think it will work if it is still inside a "container" that keeps it inside (to the up right). get rid of wrapper and main-wrap and all the margins set to the body, did you remove the body from: padding: 0; margin: 0;?